# Moving an image when browser resizes

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Sorry for this really noob question, but for some reason, I just can't figure it out why it wont work. Basically, I am trying to move the Logo next to the header menu. The logo will stay right next to the header menu even when the browser re sizes.

Code:

Html

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
    <div class="logo-name">
        <a href="/"><img src ="/images/logo.png" alt="Company Logo" /></a>
    </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="bar nav">
    <div class="nav-outer">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-inner"> 
    Home, Products... </div></div>etc...
```

CSS

```
.header:after {
    background-color: #1D2124;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 92px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
div.logo {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
}
.bar:before, .bar:after {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.bar:before, .bar:after {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.nav {
    min-height: 33px;
    top: 53px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    left: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 890px;
}
```

Image: http://imageshack.us/f/40/c4dr.png/

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: In your html structure place your div logo after the closing </div> of bar nav div. Try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like that?

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="sub logo"></div>
        <div class="sub">link</div>
        <div class="sub">link</div>
        <div class="sub">link</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sub{
    width:auto;
    height:20px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
    min-width:40px;
}
.logo{
    background:blue;
}
.main{
    background:red;
    height:40px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3JrN/)

Comment: Thank you, it was quite not exactly like this, but this one provided the most help.